# Cmake could not find boost

Tags: cmake

I would like to build a program based on PCL 1.8.1 
I installed all-in-one PCl 1.8.1, which include Eigen, Boost, etc.. all that needs to run the program
I set all environmental-variable.

This is my "CMakeList.txt" file

> if(BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS) # if compiling with PCL, it will bring Eigen with it
>       message(STATUS "will use BOOST")
>       include_directories(${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
>       add_definitions( -DUSE_BOOST )
>   endif()

and this is CMake program [image]

When I configure it, CMake couldn't find Boost, but Boost file is in the right folder

[image]

Does anybody know how to solve this problem? I can't solve this problem for 6 hours..

CMakeList.txt

```
project(ExploringSfMWithOpenCV)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0074 OLD)

find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
if(EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS) # if compiling with PCL, it will bring Eigen with it
    message(STATUS "will use Eigen")
    include_directories(${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_definitions( -DUSE_EIGEN )
endif()

if(BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS) # if compiling with PCL, it will bring Eigen with it
    message(STATUS "will use BOOST")
    include_directories(${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_definitions( -DUSE_BOOST )
endif()


set(SSBA_LIBRARY_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/3rdparty/SSBA-3.0/build" CACHE PATH "Directory to find SSBA libs")

set(OpenCV_FOUND 1)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
link_directories(
    ${SSBA_LIBRARY_DIR}
    )

IF(APPLE)
    set( COCOA_LIBS ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework )
    set( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -F/usr/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib")
ENDIF(APPLE)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

link_directories(${SSBA_LIBRARY_DIR})
include_directories(${SSBA_LIBRARY_DIR}/../)

set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -D__SFM__DEBUG__" )

# Core functions of SfM
file(GLOB SFM_LIB_SOURCES
    Distance.*
    Triangulation.*
    FindCameraMatrices.*
    MultiCameraDistance.*
    IDistance.*
    MultiCameraPnP.*
    Common.*
    IFeatureMatcher.*
    RichFeatureMatcher.*
    OFFeatureMatcher.*
    BundleAdjuster.*
    GPUSURFFeatureMatcher.*
    AbstractFeatureMatcher.*
    SfMUpdateListener.*
)

add_library( ExploringSfMLibrary ${SFM_LIB_SOURCES} )
if(MSVC)
    set_target_properties(ExploringSfMLibrary PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/openmp")
    target_link_libraries(ExploringSfMLibrary V3D COLAMD )
endif()
if(APPLE)
    # default is to build SSBA as static libs...
    target_link_libraries(ExploringSfMLibrary
        "${SSBA_LIBRARY_DIR}/libV3D.a"
        "${SSBA_LIBRARY_DIR}/libCOLAMD.a"
        )

    set_target_properties(ExploringSfMLibrary PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-fopenmp")
    set_target_properties(ExploringSfMLibrary PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-fopenmp")
endif()


# UI part
add_executable(ExploringSfMExec
    Visualization.cpp
    Visualization.h
    main.cpp
    )


target_link_libraries(ExploringSfMExec
            ExploringSfMLibrary
            ${OpenCV_LIBS}
            ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
            V3D
            colamd
            )
```

Comment: Is this really your full `CMakeLists.txt` file? Then you are clearly missing the `find_package` command, e.g. `find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options)`

Comment: I added the full CMakeLists.txt file. find_package command exists in there.